# Sql query working when executing on Database but not on Python

Tags: python, sql

Hell All, I am trying to execute the below query. It is working when executing on the Database but when tring to execute on python scrip getting error:

`OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,2), (3,4)) t1 (c1, c2)
```

Python:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,2), (3,4)) t1 (c1, c2)')
```

**OUTPUT ERROR**

`OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

**Expected problem**

I think there is problem when creating temporary table t1 with fields c1 & c2.

Comment: use cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,2), (3,4) ') like vise

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1','2'), ('3','4')) t1 ('c1', 'c2')")
```

Comment: Getting the same error...OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: What database is this?  I do not recognise the syntax as valid for table creation.  I do recognse it as derived table syntax - but the derived table only exists for the lifetime of the query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1','2'), ('3','4')) t1 ('c1', 'c2')'''
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Then, I think the error is not related to syntax but it is related to the logic. What database language is this?  You can find the current language of SQL Server is by executing the following script:

```select * from sys.syslanguages where langid=@@langid```

That way we can suggest solutions specific to that language

Comment: I am using DB2 database.